# Modifying a list of files based on the filename extension

Tags: ant

I have a .txt file with below entries

```
filename.type1
filename.type1
filename.type2
filename.type3
filename.type3
filename.type4
filename.type5
```

For any and all entries of .type1 and .type2, it shall delete and then add respective entry in .txt file as filename_important.type1, or .type2.

Modified file shall look like:

```
filename_important.type1
filename_important.type1
filename_important.type2
filename.type3
filename.type3
filename.type4
filename.type5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`<replaceregexp>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task, for example:

```
<replaceregexp file="file.txt" byline="true">
    <regexp pattern="\.(type1|type2)$"/>
    <substitution expression="_important.\1"/>
</replaceregexp>
```